# SQL joining two tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, auto-populating

I have 2 tables employees(id and name) and salary(id, salary), the 1st has 4 rows and 2nd has 2 rows.

```
table 1            Table 2
id   Name         id    salary
1     Sue          1    10000 
2    Sarah         3     9000
3    Nick 
4    james
```

I want a join as follows

```
id   Name     Salary
1     Sue     10000
2    Sarah    No Salary
3    Nick     9000
4    james    No salary
```

Comment: So you created an account here just to ask us do your homework? In the same time you could have googled about SQL JOINs and finish the assignment.

Comment: How much do I get with "Bo salary"? "Bo" as in "Bonus", right?

Comment: Come on guys.. I am beginer with SQL so posted such a question.. Do not reply if you think that was too dumb..

Comment: They're saying you should have done some reading, *tried something*, then come here to ask questions if you still didn't understand.  Otherwise, you risk learning Cargo Cult programming - you get the little bit that plugs in and works, but don't know *why* it works.

Comment: @DaveE what bothered me the most was the sheer number of people answering who didn't grasp they needed an outer join.

Comment: @HLGEM- I understand completely. I work with folks who for years have supported a product based on SQL Server and who do not understand that all JOINs are not created equal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT e.id, e.name , s.salary FROM employees e 
LEFT JOIN salary s
ON e.id=s.id
ORDER BY e.id ASC
```

Comment: Your comment implies that you don't quite understand what an OUTER join is.

Comment: A wrong answer should not be the selected answer, there are correct answers below.

Answer (score 7):

To get all rows from `T1` when joining to table `T2` that is lacking the rows 2 and 4 you need to use a [left outer join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx). For row 2 and 4 salary will be null.

To replace the null value with something else you can use [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx). Coalesce returns the first nonnull argument.

Since field `salary` is declared as an `int` field and you want `No Salary` as output where there is no salary you need to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) the `int` to a `varchar` before using it as an argument in coalesce.

```
declare @T1 table(id int, name varchar(10))
declare @T2 table(id int, salary int)

insert into @T1 values(1, 'Sue')
insert into @T1 values(2, 'Sarah')
insert into @T1 values(3, 'Nick')
insert into @T1 values(4, 'james') 

insert into @T2 values(1, 10000)
insert into @T2 values(3, 9000)

select
  T1.id,
  T1.name,
  coalesce(cast(T2.salary as varchar(10)), 'No Salary') as salary 
from @T1 as T1
  left outer join @T2 as T2
    on T1.id = T2.id
```

Result

```
id          name       salary
----------- ---------- ----------
1           Sue        10000
2           Sarah      No Salary
3           Nick       9000
4           james      No Salary
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e.id, e.name , 
case
when s.salary is null then 'no salary'
else cast(s.salary as varchar)
end
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN salary s
ON e.id=s.id
order by e.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to list all employees, regardless of whether or not they have a listed salary, so you should be using a `LEFT JOIN`. An inner join would potentially list salaries for employees that no longer have a listing in the Employee table and an implicit join (I believe) would be missing rows.

Something like this should do what you need:

`SELECT E.id, E.name, S.salary FROM Employees E LEFT JOIN Salary S ON E.id = S.id`

Comment: But i want 'No Salary' in the column of salary for employees without any salary